# Invalid SSL option using the Authorize.NET PHP SDK

Tags: php, ssl, authorize.net

I am trying to charge a card using Authorize.NET's PHP SDK. But it keeps giving me this error:

```
 Thu, 29 Mar 2018 17:00:56 +0000 ERROR : [_sendRequest] (/lib/shared/AuthorizeNetRequest.php : 100) - ----Request---- Invalid SSL option
```

It has worked before, but now it keeps giving me a error, I have researched this but have found no answer, I have tried this in my code:

```
$sale->VERIFY_PEER = false;
```

I have also updated my `cert.pem` file but it still gives me a error.

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use lib\net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
use lib\net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController;


define("AUTHORIZENET_LOG_FILE", "phplog");
$usermeta = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), '_carddetails_', TRUE);
define("AUTHORIZENET_API_LOGIN_ID", "[LOGIN_ID]");
define("AUTHORIZENET_TRANSACTION_KEY", "[TRANSACTION_KEY]");
define("AUTHORIZENET_SANDBOX", true);
$sale = new AuthorizeNetAIM(AUTHORIZENET_API_LOGIN_ID, AUTHORIZENET_TRANSACTION_KEY);
$sale->VERIFY_PEER = false;
$sale->amount   = $_POST['grandTotal'];
$sale->card_num = $usermeta['number'];
$sale->exp_date = $usermeta['expdate'];
$sale->addLineItem('item1', // Item Id
    'Order 1', // Item Name
    'Order 1', // Item Description
    '1', // Item Quantity
    $_POST['grandTotal'], // Item Unit Price
    'N' // Item taxable
);
$customer              = (object) array();
$customer->first_name  = $usermeta['firstname'];
$customer->last_name   = $usermeta['lastname'];
$customer->company     = $usermeta['company'];
$customer->address     = $usermeta['address'];
$customer->city        = $usermeta['city'];
$customer->state       = $usermeta['state'];
$customer->zip         = $usermeta['zip'];
$customer->country     = $usermeta['country'];
$customer->cust_id     = 9999;
$customer->customer_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sale->setFields($customer);

$response      = $sale->authorizeAndCapture();
$responseCode  = $response->response_code;
$authCode      = $response->authorization_code;
$avsResultCode = $response->avs_response;
$transId       = $response->transaction_id;
$transHash     = $response->md5_hash;
$accountNumber = $response->account_number;
$accountType   = $response->card_type;
$description   = $response->description;
if ($response->approved)
{
   echo "iT worked";
}
else
{
    echo $response->error_message;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.

I commented this out:

```
$sale->VERIFY_PEER = false;
```

And commented line 80 of HttpClient.php

Here is where I found the answer at: https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php/issues/223

Answer (score 1):

You should grab the latest cert from https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php/tree/master/lib/ssl.  It was last updated 5 days ago as of writing this post to include new Authorize certs.

Disabling or changing the default peer and cert verification could be dangerous.

Comment: I have done that, But It did not work, I have already fixed my problem anyways, Please see my answer!